# Is Bourdon tube affected by the cross sectional shape of the tube?

Tags: pressure, measurements

I've been searching for the working of pressure measuring tools , and i know that what makes the bourdon tube straighten is the distribution of the pressure on its walls  .so 
my question is , in bourdon tube pressure gauge does the expansion of the tube depend on its cross sectional shape ?and if so ....
what happens when the cross section is a uniform circular shape ?
////////

Answer (score 0):

most bourdon tubes are of circular cross-section, or nearly so. However, for measuring low pressures in the range of 1 to 5 psi, the tube will not only have a thin wall but it will be flattened into a rectangular cross-section, with semicircular sides, and with the broad axis at right angles to the length of the curved tube.